# Codeigniter dynamic date range

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I was asked to create some reports using charts. I'm started studying programming recently so I might be asking something kinda stupid, but I'm really struggling with this one. I was able to draw the charts using google charts and querying my db BUT I don't know how to implement a date range picker. Here is my model, well, one of them...

```
public function tester() {

 $this->db->where('type_id', 7);
 $this->db->where('entry_date >', '2016-05-11');
 $this->db->where('entry_date <', 'curdate()', FALSE);
 $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, count(type_id) AS totals');
 $this->db->from('entries');
 $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = entries.user_id');
 $this->db->group_by('entries.user_id');
 $this->db->order_by('totals', 'DESC');
 $this->db->limit(3);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 return $query->result();

}
```

Those dates in the where statements are there for testing purposes, it works just fine. Question is: How can I dynamically modify this query based on an start and end date selected by the user and redraw the chart?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you would make the dates variables that would be passed from the user selection "somehow"

Comment: You probably want a date range, start/end date, and you need to add those as parameters to your function and use those in your db query.

Answer (score 1):

Usually with a start and end date range, you want to include the dates so i showed it as >= But you can also just make it > if you really need greater then etc.

```
public function tester($startDate,$endDate) {

 $this->db->where('type_id', 7);
 $this->db->where('entry_date >=', $startDate);
 $this->db->where('entry_date <=', $endDate);
 $this->db->select('first_name, last_name, count(type_id) AS totals');
 $this->db->from('entries');
 $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = entries.user_id');
 $this->db->group_by('entries.user_id');
 $this->db->order_by('totals', 'DESC');
 $this->db->limit(3);
 $query = $this->db->get();

 return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  makes perfect sense.  So I suppose that to actually get the start and end dates I would use something like jQuery Date Range Picker,  right?  I've been messing around with it and it's simple enough to apply the selected range to an input field and post it to a php variable.  Problem is that it sends both start and end date together with one input.  How could I separate it in 2 different variables so I can send it to my model?